# SQL Server 2014 UNION in CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql-server, union, cross-apply

I have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    d.UserName, 
    i.itemID, 
    d.Score, 
    d.StoreCode, 
    d.Location
FROM 
    G.dbo.Users d
LEFT JOIN 
    G.dbo.Emails s on d.UserName=s.UserName
CROSS APPLY 
    (
        SELECT TOP (1) 
            ii.ItemID 
        FROM 
            G.dbo.Dump ii
        WHERE 
            ii.Username=d.UserName
        AND 
            ii.endTime>DATEADD(hh,3,getDate())
    ) i
WHERE 
    s.serName is null
AND 
    d.Score>@_Score
AND 
    (d.processed=0)
GROUP BY 
    d.UserName, 
    i.itemID, 
    d.Score, 
    d.StoreCode, 
    d.Location
ORDER BY 
    d.UserName ASC
```

Now I need to modify it since Table `G.dbo.Dump` has been splitted into 20 smaller tables and now I have `Dump_00` to `Dump_19`
I try to modify part of the `CROSS APPLY` section using `UNION` in this way

```
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP (1) 
        ii.ItemID
    FROM
        (
            SELECT TOP (1) FROM G.dbo.Dump_00
            UNION
            SELECT TOP (1) FROM G.dbo.Dump_01
            UNION
            .....
            SELECT TOP (1) FROM G.dbo.Dump_19
        ) ii
    WHERE 
        ii.UserName=d.UserName
    AND 
        ii.EndTime>DATEADD(hh,3,getDate())
) i
```

but result is not working as expected

can suggest if `UNION` is the right way and in case how to apply, or another solution?

Thanks!

Comment: what is it supposed to return? `TOP 1’` without `ORDER BY` doesn't guarantee any particular row.

Comment: So we need to be mind readers too, to know what "is not working as expected" actually means?

Comment: @MartinSmith It is supposed to return Username and First (still active) Item  of users present in Sellers Table but not in Emails Table.   
Concerning TOP 1, yes, you're right, but it is enough it returns a random item with endtime>DateAdd... not added Order BY to reduce processing time since Dump Table was more than 100 Million Records.

Comment: @JamesZ, _not working as expected_ means that is not returning the same result as the original Query, if we want to go deeper, the solution I adopted, changing `CROSS APPLY` does not return any result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `TOP 1` from the union elements. Not sure why that was added. Logically, you are after a set that is the union of all tables.

Also, I don't think you want a union at all. You want the concatenation.

```
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP (1) ii.ItemID
    FROM
        (
            SELECT FROM G.dbo.Dump_00 --changed
            UNION ALL --changed
            SELECT FROM G.dbo.Dump_01 --changed
            .....
        ) ii
) i
```

Comment: Hmmm.. what do you mean ' you dont'w want a union at all, you want the concatenaton?' considering that removing top 1 seems working.. how can I achieve concatenation instead of union?

Comment: If you split up the rows you probably want all of them, not all of them plus a distinct operation. Union does an implicit distinct.